# does not work on lenova G400 laptop

Tags: system-installation

I installed ubundu from cd after instalation (did not installed drivers)i reboot the system the got an error message on screen'your system graphics is law' my system have intel i5,AMD 2GB dedicated graphics How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the AMD graphics drivers. Check this link and [follow the instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).